# Jenkins complete workspace link for running job - link to screenshot my job creates

Tags: jenkins

Running `Jenkins ver. 2.150.1`

I have a script that logs a URL of a file that gets generated when running unit tests.  This is a generated file that I want to print a valid URL to in the log file.

The job name is `test-staging` and the pipeline branch is `level0` and the build number is `3` and when I call `System.getenv("BUILD_URL")` I get the following:

http://jenkins.mydomain/job/test-staging/job/level0/3

The file I want to link to is the workspace in the `screenshot` directory, and if I browse to it via Jenkins I get:

`http://jenkins.mydomain/job/test-staging/job/level0/3/execution/node/3/ws/screenshot/error1.png`

So, the location is `BUILD_URL + 'execution/node/3/ws/' + screenshotLocation`

How do I get the "Node number" or whatever the 3 represents here?  I don't see it in an environment variable (I do this in the test):

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> me : System.getenv().entrySet()){
            log.info("  Environment Dump - var {} :: {}", me.getKey(), me.getValue());
}
```

The output from above is:

```
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var JAVA_HOME :: /home/dev/jdk
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR :: /home/dev/project
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var OLDPWD :: /home/dev/project
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var TERM :: xterm
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var BUILD_NUMBER :: 3
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var HOSTNAME :: a80e5d3525ef
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var BUILD_URL :: http://jenkins.mydomain/job/test-staging/job/level0/3
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var M2_HOME :: /home/dev/apache-maven-3.5.4
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var _JAVA_OPTIONS :: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var PWD :: /home/dev/project
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var SHLVL :: 1
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var HOME :: /home/dev
10:13:22 INFO  -   Environment Dump - var MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS ::  -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar:9000 clean compile -
```

How do I determine the location of the workspace here?  Particularly, the 3 in `/node/3`?

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if someone implements an environment variable that we can query from the Jenkins instance (I found at least one similar request for that, see https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-61821).

For me, I ended up with a very dirty hack:

```
def STRANGE_ID = sh script: """curl --user user:passwd ${BUILD_URL}ws/ | awk --field-separator='/' '/a href=.*execution.*node.*ws/ { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if(\$i=="execution" && \$(i+1)=="node" && \$(i+3)=="ws") { printf( "" \$(i+2) ""); } } } ' """, returnStdout:true
echo "detected strange hidden node executor id: ${STRANGE_ID}";
```

It requests and parses the "workspace"-html-page (..ws/). At this page, there is a link including that strange id after execution/node. Unfortunately, user credentials are need for the Jenkins instance.